# Black strips on ios application

Tags: iphone, launchimage

Here is image first time it was showing black strips at the top and bottom of ios application so to remove that i did some changes in app icons and launch images, this change removed black strips for all devices for iPhone 6, 6 Plus also. But UI for iPhone 6, 6 Plus and iPad Pro is like above image what to do to show it correctly link for image

Comment: Did you miss one of the images?

Comment: could you suggest me sizes for lauchimages?

Comment: Try reading this article http://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-scaled-images-with-pdf-vectors/ . You might be able to save some headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Once you used the LaunchImage and you put a `@3x` image, the app will be UI compatible with iPhone6 and 6plus. I guess your XIB and Storyboard are using fixed dimensions to iPhone5 and now your elements are not fitting the new width of the screen.

Comment: You can remove from the LaunchImage the @3x image

Comment: In LaunchImage there is no any image . I just set constraint for LaunchScreen and added launch image in imageview

Comment: You haven't to use the LaunchImage.storyboard

Comment: then what i need to use

Answer (score 0):

May be you did not use launce images for iPhone 6, 6+.

Use these 2 images with '*image name and size*'  as **Launchimage**
from **Image.xcassets** do likewise [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va6zu.jpg)

```
Default-iPhone6.png (750x1334)
Default-iPhone6Plus.png (1242x2208)
```

**Note:** As you should use launceimages for all devices. So if you don's use '*launceimage*' for specific device, you will see blank screen of that device.

Comment: how to add images and where?

Comment: if I do not add images on LaunchScreen and if i only create xib  or storyboard for LaunchScreen still it's not working properly